# 'show desktop' crashes if nautilus is running on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, 14.10, show-desktop

I am using Ubuntu 14.10, kernel 3.19.3-031903-generic, nautilus version 3.12.2

My problem is that whenever I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keys or even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to hide everything and go to desktop, my system crashes **IF** an instance of nautilus is open, ie, I can run multiple programs and still do 'show desktop', but as soon as I open nautilus and do 'show desktop', my system crashes.

Is there anyone who has the same problem and is there a solution to it?

Comment: You could try purging and re-installing `nautilus`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just realized it was because of the theme "zukitwo dark theme" I was using.